# Getting different results from PYTHON online IDE and PYCHARM. EOF ERROR

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error

**I want to know what's wrong with this code, gives a different result on PYCHARM than it does on an editor online. **

*PYCHARM*

```
print("Input the value of x & y")
x, y = map(int, input().split(":"))
print("The value of x & y are: ", x, y)
```

*With an error:*

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdullahhomefolder/Desktop/pycharm/masters_proje/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    x, y = map(int, input().split(":"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    21 21
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

*ONLINE*

```
Input the value of x & y
 12:21
The value of x & y are:  12 21
```

Comment: Make sure PyCharm is using Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: It worked....So silly, THANKS @Barmar